# Are goroutines appropriate for large, parallel, compute-bound problems?

Tags: parallel-processing, go, goroutine

Are go-routines pre-emptively multitasked for numerical problems?

I am very intrigued by the lean design of Go, the speed, but most by the fact that channels are first-class objects. I hope the last point may enable a whole new class of deep-analysis algorithms for big data, via the complex interconnection patterns which they should allow.

My problem domain requires real-time compute-bound analysis of streaming incoming data. The data can be partitioned into between 100-1000 "problems" each of which will take between 10 and 1000 seconds to compute (ie their granularity is highly variable). Results must however *all* be available before the output makes sense, ie, say 500 problems come in, and all 500 must be solved before I can use any of them. The application must be able to scale, potentially to thousands (but unlikely 100s of thousands) problems.

Given that I am less worried about numerical library support (most of this stuff is custom), Go seems ideal as I can map each problem to a goroutine. Before I invest in learning Go rather than say, Julia, Rust, or a functional language (none of which, as far as I can see, have first-class channels so for me are at an immediate disadvantage) I need to know if goroutines are *properly* pre-emptively multi-tasked. That is, if I run 500 compute-bound goroutines on a powerful multicore computer, can I expect reasonably load balancing across all the "problems" or will I have to cooperatively "yield" all the time, 1995-style. This issue is particularly important given the variable granularity of the problem and the fact that, during compute, I usually will not know how much longer it will take.

If another language would serve me better, I am happy to hear about it, but I have a requirement that threads (or go/coroutines) of execution be lightweight. Python multiprocessing module for example, is far too resource intensive for my scaling ambitions. Just to pre-empt: I *do* understand the difference between parallelism and concurrency.

Comment: As far as I know, Go does exactly that. If all Go routines are non-blocking, Go switches between them time-slice based.

Comment: And is heavy numerical computing "non blocking"? What *does* block a goroutine?

Comment: @Thomad Browne: Blocking function are those that need to suspend you Go-routine until a result is available, such as sending to / receiving from a channel, calling runtime.Gosched() or doing IO. If your function does none of these. it's not a blocking function.

Comment: Aside: As of today (late 2017), Julia *does* have channel support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Go runtime has a model where multiple Go routines are mapped onto multiple threads in an automatic fashion. No Go routine is bound to a certain thread, the scheduler may (and will) schedule Go routines to the next available thread. The number of threads a Go program uses is taken from the `GOMAXPROCS` environment variable and can be overriden with [runtime.GOMAXPROCS](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS)(). This is a simplified description which is sufficient for understanding.

Go routines may yield in the following cases:

- On any operation that might block, i.e. any operation that cannot return a result on the spot because it is either a (possible) blocking system-call like `io.Read()` or an operation that might require waiting for other Go routines, like acquiring a mutex or sending to or receiving from a channel
- On various runtime operations
- On function call if the scheduler detects that the preempted Go routine took a lot of CPU time (this is new in Go 1.2)
- On call to [runtime.Gosched](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched)()
- On panic()
- As of Go 1.14, tight loops can be preempted by the runtime. As a result, loops without function calls no longer potentially deadlock the scheduler or significantly delay garbage collection. This is not supported on all platforms - be sure to [review the release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#runtime). Also see issue [#36365](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36365) for future plans in this area.
- On various other occasions

The following things prevent a Go routine from yielding:

- Executing C code. A Go routine can't yield while it's executing C code via cgo.
- Calling [runtime.LockOSThread](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread)(), until [runtime.UnlockOSThread](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#UnlockOSThread)() has been called.

Comment: Two very interesting bullets here: "on function call if [it] took a lot of CPU time". That's my use case for each Go routine. Also "Executing a tight loop that doesn't contain function calls". So basically, it's not truly pre-emptive. I have to make sure I am periodically calling functions in my goroutine. I cannot have a monolithic piece of numerical code running in the goroutine, as this will block the entire thread, effectively limiting me to GOMAXPROCS parallelism. I see the scheduler has already become more sophisticated since 1.0; is there a chance it could become purely pre-emptive?

Comment: I'm thinking btw this will probably not be a problem in the sense that I can probably yield explicitly or via a function call at fixed periodic intervals, or perhaps write the algo using functions, essentially achieving my objective. I just would have liked to be able to have true pre-emption.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne You will never get more than GOMAXPROCS parallelism anyway. Also notice that the Go compiler might inline functions (even across modules), especially if they are non-recursive / only contain computations.

Comment: @ThomasBrown I can only speculate about whether Go will become fully preemptive. Most applications don't require that (in fact, only applications that do a lot of computationally expensive tasks do) and it's quite tricky to get right, outright impossible on some platforms. Consider pinning the Go routine that accepts incoming data to an OS thread or better profile before you do such a thing.

Comment: yes I understood that I would never get more than GOMAXPROCX parallelism when I "hit the metal", but the algo depends on load balancing - that is, faster serial results are much less useful than parallel results that are all slower to compute. Also, in the interest of scalability proper pre-emptiveness would have been good as I could just add hardware. It seems I now have two levels of parallelism. Not really a problem as I think you are right that most applications, indeed including mine, probably don't need thousands of preemptive threads as we can use other techniques. Still ... ;)

Comment: Please update the answer to include the results of https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10958

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand you, however you can set [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) to scale to all processes, then use channels (or locks) to synchronize the data, example:

```
const N = 100

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()) //scale to all processors
    var stuff [N]bool
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int, runtime.NumCPU())
    done := make(chan struct{}, runtime.NumCPU())
    go func() {
        for i := range ch {
            stuff[i] = true
        }
    }()
    wg.Add(N)
    for i := range stuff {
        go func(i int) {

            for { //cpu bound loop
                select {
                case <-done:
                    fmt.Println(i, "is done")
                    ch <- i
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                default:
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        for _ = range stuff {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
            done <- struct{}{}
        }
        close(done)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
    for i, v := range stuff { //false-postive datarace
        if !v {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%d != true", i))
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("All done")
}
```

EDIT: Information about the scheduler @ http://tip.golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c

> ### Goroutine scheduler
>
> The scheduler's job is to distribute ready-to-run  goroutines over worker threads.
>
> The main concepts are:
>
> - G - goroutine.
> - M - worker thread, or machine.
> - P - processor, a resource that is required to execute Go code. M must have an associated P to execute Go code, however it can be blocked or in a syscall w/o an associated P.
>
> Design doc at http://golang.org/s/go11sched.

Comment: I think he wants to know whether the Go scheduler is preemptive.

Comment: This looks really interesting but I do not yet know enough about Go to make complete sense of what is being done in the code. I have successfully compiled and executed it, seems like I get pretty serial-like behaviour. I thought I would have gotten most of the 100 results "bunching" during output? What I would like to do is modify your code so that the workload in each goroutine is approximately equal, then I can see how the returns over time profile behaves for various N...

Comment: In my understanding you are launching 100 go routines, and when they're done they tell me so, but how much work are you giving each one to do?

Comment: All 100 should theoretically be running in the same time, when one finishes it pushes the results to the channel, the reason it looks serial is the fact I only sleep for 1 microsecond before signalling a random goroutine that it's done (notice the `done <- struct{}{}`), if you add random sleeps it will look different.